# Настройка url в modx

Tags: url, modx

Нужно, чтобы на сайте, ко всем ссылка в конце добавлялся закрывающий слэш "/" и если в url будет несколько слэшей, чтобы дубли удалялись и оставалось только по 1.
Если в ручную добавить слэш в конце, то он почему-то автоматически стирается, и если задавать слеш в ссылках, он все равно удаляется.
Как можно решить эту задачу средствами modx или при помощи htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У папок слэш добавляется автоматически, а у обычных урлов проще всего сделать через замену `.html` на `/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В системных настройках modx в пункт Дружественные URL есть параметр Символы, вырезаемые из псевдонима. Если уберете оттуда слеш - он не будет вырезаться. А повторяющиеся слеши можно убрать как раз в .htaccess. Сама правда не пробовала. Вот тут на эту тему https://toster.ru/q/232562